# Deploy ASP.NET application to another directory inside the website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I made an other application inside my website on IIS. But I cannot get it to deploy to this application, instead it always deploys to the root of my website.

[image: Website structure]
[image: File structure]

It has to publish to the api folder (yellow), but instead it publish to the root of the website (selected). **How can I configure my website to pubish to the correct folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are using Visual Studio and you are using Publish Profiles.

And I suspect your Publish Profile could be set like this:

- Site Name: Prd-A1086-AMDM
- Destination URL: http://{your-domain}/api

Instead, you should have it like this:

- Site Name: Prd-A1086-AMDM/api   (Note the subsite **/api**)
- Destination URL: http://{your-domain}/api